background change animation
I have the following piece of code:
      <main class="page" id="page">
        <div class="holder">
          <div class="slide group1">
            <div class="slide__lines"></div>
            <div class="slide__inner">
              <div class="group1__bg"></div>
              <div class="group1__lines"></div>
              <div class="container">
                <div class="slide__text text-top">
                  <h1>We create <span class="gradient">IT solutions</span> that recoup investment and increase efficiency of your business</h1>
                  <a href="#contacts" class="btn">Submit</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="scroll-down">
                <div class="text">
                  <span>scroll down</span>
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 27 50" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="26" height="49" rx="13" stroke="#434758" stroke-opacity="0.5" />
                    <rect x="12.5" y="8.5" width="2" height="10" rx="1" stroke="#434758" stroke-opacity="0.5" class="line" />
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

setTimeout(function () {
    var group1 = document.querySelector('.group1');
    var group1Text = group1.querySelector('h1');
    var group1Bg = group1.querySelector('.group1__bg');
    var submitBtn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    var slideLines = group1.querySelectorAll('.slide__lines');
    group1.classList.add('custom-color');

    group1Text.textContent = "We help businesses grow through their automation. We accelerate the internal workflows of companies, increase efficiency, minimize routine tasks, and reduce costs.";
    group1Text.classList.add('fade-in');
    group1Text.style.color = "#fff";

    group1Bg.style.opacity = '0';
    setTimeout(function () {
        group1Bg.style.background = "#1D1F23";
        group1Bg.style.opacity = '100';
        group1Bg.style.transition = "opacity 1s ease";
        group1Bg.style.backgroundImage = "url('../images/lines.svg')";
        group1Bg.style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        group1Bg.style.backgroundSize = "cover";
        group1Bg.style.animation = "none";

        slideLines.forEach(function (slideLine) {
            slideLine.style.position = "absolute";
            slideLine.style.left = "10vw";
            slideLine.style.right = "10vw";
            slideLine.style.bottom = "0";
            slideLine.style.top = "0";
            slideLine.style.borderLeft = "1px solid #323544";
            slideLine.style.borderRight = "1px solid #323544";
            slideLine.style.zIndex = "1";
        });

        submitBtn.style.opacity = "0";
        submitBtn.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease";
        setTimeout(function () {
            submitBtn.style.opacity = "0";
        }, 100);

        setTimeout(function () {
            group1Bg.style.opacity = '1';
            submitBtn.style.display = "none";
            group1Bg.style.animation = "move-bg 15s linear infinite";
        }, 100);
    }, 100);
}, 5000);

This is an animation of changing the background and text, you need to make it so that it works when scrolling.
How to explain this correctly, we need that when we scroll the page it does not scroll but remains in this section, after a couple of scrolls we should have this animation play and then we can scroll through other sections, I have no ideas on how to implement this. I made a slightly different code with scrolling, but it scrolls the section, but this should not happen.
I will be grateful if someone can explain and help.
complete and fix animation

Something like this? https://codepen.io/daveredfern/pen/zBGBJV

no, the animation should be like in the code above, you just need to somehow scroll so that it remains in place, and after playing the animation you can scroll further.

So make your animated elements position sticky or absolute for the timeout period that coincides with the animations duration, then change its position once the animation duration is completed. Perhaps if you show an example of what you are looking to achieve may help others grasp what your intent is.
